# Conditional/cascading/dependent drop-down list

Tags: list, validation, excel, excel-formula, vba

I am essentially trying to do that this guy is trying to do:
[Excel drop-down list using vLookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261951/excel-drop-down-list-using-vlookup)

I've gone through the steps and since my data set has about 400 different drop down options I am hoping there is an easier way than naming ranges. I have a list of about 400 different account names. Each of these account names is tied to a household and identified by the household ID number. A household can have anywhere from 1-5 account names. I would like for my drop down menu to be able to identify a household ID number and then provide the drop down with the account names associated with it.

Example:

[image: Data]

Where household Id number is the identifier.

I've gone here as well http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/data-validation/dynamic-indirect  and am trying to find a way to save on some of the manual work.I am a total newbie so thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend you have three worksheets.  The first worksheet, `Sheet1`, is the sheet that your users will be looking at and it has the drop down lists.  We'll say that the cell containing the first drop down option is in B1 (the one with about 400 different options) and the cell containing the dependent drop down is in B2:

[image: Sheet1 example]

On your second sheet, which we'll call `MasterList`, is all of the data options and the corresponding data.  Row 1 is a header row; Row 2 and down is the actual data:

[image: MasterList example]

On your third sheet, which we'll call `DropDownLists`, is where the magic happens.  It first needs to have a list of all the unique data options.  I've put that in column A.  You can get the unique data options from your master list through whatever means you prefer (Advanced Filter, Pivot Table, formula, VBA, etc).  That list of unique data options is the basis of your drop down list for `Sheet1` cell B1.  Then in cell B2 of `DropDownLists` and copied down as far as needed to guarantee it will grab all data associated with the selected Data Option, use this formula (adjust sheet names and ranges to suit your actual data):

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!$B$1="",ROW(B1)>COUNTIF(MasterList!$A$2:$A$10000,Sheet1!$B$1)),"",INDEX(MasterList!$B$2:$B$10000,MATCH(1,INDEX((MasterList!$A$2:$A$10000=Sheet1!$B$1)*(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,MasterList!$B$2:$B$10000)=0),),0)))
```

This makes your `DropDownLists` sheet look like this:

[image: DropDownLists example]

Lastly, we need to make that list (data based on the selected Data Option) a dynamic named range.  I named it `listFilteredData` and defined it with this formula:

```
=DropDownLists!$B$2:INDEX(DropDownLists!$B:$B,MAX(2,ROWS(DropDownLists!$B:$B)-COUNTBLANK(DropDownLists!$B:$B)))
```

Then for `Sheet1` cell B2, use Data Validation and define the list with `=listFilteredData` and you will get results as shown in my example.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to map this out. The problem I am running into is that I have I have ID numbers that are attached to more than one data point. For example, a household may have 2 or 3 different accounts and each account is currently labeled by the household ID number. Using the first formula you provided for the DropDownLists sheet I am only able to get the first account name associated with the household ID number. Thanks in advance for any additional guidance you can provide.

Comment: @Jmrunnels I'd have to see some example data.  Can you edit your original question to include what your data looks like?

Comment: Edits made in original questions. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jmrunnels I have edited the answer to account for your provided example data.  Note that it is basically identical, I just switched which column the formula looks at to generate the list of filtered accounts.  If you need to know how to get all the unique items from a list (in this case it would be getting all of the unique IDs), have a look at AdvancedFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Practice with this.....it will get what you need.

Your data will have to sorted for this to work.

**Sorted Data**

[image: Sorted Data]

**Data Validation for Shows**

[image]

[image]

**Data Validation for Episodes**

This formula in the data validation box

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($E$4,$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A:$A,$E$4),1)
```

[image]

[image]

Enter the array formula to find the Duration
Must be confirmed with **Ctrl & Shift & Enter**

`=INDEX($C$4:$C$18,MATCH(1,(E4=$A$4:$A$18)*(F4=$B$4:$B$18),0))`
[image]